# Necessary and sufficient condition for convergence in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$ be a sequence of random variables on some common probability space. Prove that

$$
X_n \xrightarrow{P}X   \Longleftrightarrow  \mathbb{E}[|X_n-X| \wedge 1]=0
$$

where $\wedge$ stands for the minimum of two functions.

Can any one provide a hint for the same ?

I started with $|X_n-X|\wedge 1= |X_n-X| \mathbb{1} _{\{|X_n-X|\leq 1\}}+ 1_{\{|X_n-X| > 1\}}$ and took expectations on both sides but I am unable to properly use the given information in the above approach.

Comment: For a start you might wish to use that, for every $\varepsilon$ in $(0,1)$, $$\varepsilon P(|X_n-X|\geqslant\varepsilon)\leqslant E(|X_n-X|\wedge1)\leqslant\varepsilon+P(|X_n-X|\geqslant\varepsilon).$$

Comment: For the other direction you could use Markov's inequality.
$$P\{\lvert X_n - X\rvert \wedge 1 \geq \varepsilon\} \leq \frac{E[\lvert X_n - X\rvert \wedge 1]}{\varepsilon}$$

Comment: @Did: Thanks. I was using $\epsilon=1$ and that's why failing to deduce any useful result.